# what is the error in the import statements

Tags: python, pyqt5, python-import, qfiledialog

i  am trying to create a fileDialog that will display a Window that allow the user to search for files.

but the system is displaying this error :

```
[pylint] E0611:No name 'QApplication' in module 'PyQt5.QtWidgets'
[pylint] E0611:No name 'QWidget' in module 'PyQt5.QtWidgets' [pylint]
E0611:No name 'QInputDialog' in module 'PyQt5.QtWidgets' [pylint]
E0611:No name 'QLineEdit' in module 'PyQt5.QtWidgets' [pylint]
E0611:No name 'QFileDialog' in module 'PyQt5.QtWidgets'
```

## code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QInputDialog, QLineEdit, QFileDialog
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon

class App(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'PyQt5 file dialogs - pythonspot.com'
        self.left = 10
        self.top = 10
        self.width = 640
        self.height = 480
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)

        self.openFileNameDialog()
        self.openFileNamesDialog()
        self.saveFileDialog()

        self.show()

    def openFileNameDialog(self):    
        options = QFileDialog.Options()
        options |= QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog
        fileName, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self,"QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()", "","All Files (*);;Python Files (*.py)", options=options)
        if fileName:
            print(fileName)

    def openFileNamesDialog(self):    
        options = QFileDialog.Options()
        options |= QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog
        files, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames(self,"QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames()", "","All Files (*);;Python Files (*.py)", options=options)
        if files:
            print(files)

    def saveFileDialog(self):    
        options = QFileDialog.Options()
        options |= QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog
        fileName, _ = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self,"QFileDialog.getSaveFileName()","","All Files (*);;Text Files (*.txt)", options=options)
        if fileName:
            print(fileName)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: How are you executing the script?

Comment: from the cmd or by debugging the code

Comment: in both.........

Comment: i did not understand your question

Comment: Many times this type of problem occurs because some badly configured IDE is used, or some tool that lacks additional arguments to work correctly with PyQt5.

Comment: so what can be the solution ?

Comment: That depends on the IDE or tool you are using, there is no general response.